# Google Maps Embed Error

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Don’t know if you have any experience with this or not, but in IE8 (yes, I know) the little circles I used when creating the “interactive” map for a contact page are not showing. So it just looks like a blank map. I would include the address for the site, but I only get two URLs, so I think the map URLs are more important...

The error is as follows:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; SLCC1; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Wed, 5 Oct 2011 14:18:18 UTC

Message: Unspecified error.
Line: 2093
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/371b/maps2/%7Bmain,mod_util,mod_actbr,mod_appiw,mod_info,mod_kml,mod_mp,mod_ms,mod_mssvt,mod_rst%7D.js

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 227
Char: 65
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&doflg=ptm&ie=UTF8&vpsrc=6&msid=213670049183015521580.0004ac73280983258ac07&ll=39.791655,-86.156158&spn=0.369322,0.585022&z=10&output=embed

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem that's surfaced with Google Maps and IE (I believe version 9 is affected as well).  Apparently if you upload your own custom marker icons it's reported that the problem will go away. No other known fix appears to be available right now.

Google has been notified of the problem.

See the full conversation here:
http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/maps/thread?hl=en&tid=26db8fd040386548&start=80